# PowerShell sorting problem of decimal numbers

Tags: powershell, sorting

I have an array with decimal numbers like this:

```
reihenfolge
###########
100000.00001
1000000.00001
101000.00001
101010.00001
101020.10001
```

If I sort it without parameters I get the order above. I would expect that the second number is the last entry.
I also tried to sort as int or as version or with regex, but until now I didn't find the way I expect.

```
$script:array = $script:array | Sort-Object reihenfolge

$script:array = $script:array | Sort-Object { [regex]::Replace($_.reihenfolge, '\d+', { $args[0].Value.PadLeft(20) }) }

$script:array = $script:array | Sort-Object { $_.reihenfolge -as [version] }

$script:array = $script:array | Sort-Object { $_.reihenfolge -as [int] }
```

Comment: Are the strings `reihenfolge` and `###########` actually entries in the array?

Comment: Most likely the property by which your're sorting contains string values. String sort order and numeric sort order are not the same, b/c the former compares characters at corresponding positions in the strings. Try `... | Sort-Object {[double]$_.reihenfolge}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are reading the array from a text or csv file. In that case, the numbers are actually strings, not numbers.  In order to sort numeric, try below:

1) If your array comes from a textfile, INCLUDING the lines `reihenfolge` and `###########` use the `Get-Content` cmdlet:

```
$array = Get-Content -Path 'D:\blah.txt' | Select-Object -Skip 2 | Sort-Object @{Expression = { [double]$_ }}
$array
```

2) If your data comes from a CSV file with a column named `reihenfolge`, do this:

```
$array = (Import-Csv -Path 'D:\blah.txt').reihenfolge | Sort-Object @{Expression = { [double]$_ }}
$array
```

Both will return the array sorted like this:

> ```
> 100000.00001
> 101000.00001
> 101010.00001
> 101020.10001
> 1000000.00001
> ```

Comment: thank you very much for the quick answer @Ansgar and Theo, this did the trick!! great!!